# HTML Formatting not working with UILabel in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring, xcode10

I have used this code to formatting HTML content on UILabel

```
 var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        guard let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

My HTML Content Like:

```
("<p>My Name is <b>Ayush</b> <I>Bansal</I></p>")
```

When I used above code for formatting then I get output like (My Name is Ayush Bansal).
But I want my output will be like this (My Name is **Ayush** *Bansal*)

Comment: You should get what you want. Issue is that I guess you are doing: `myLabel.text = myHTMLText. htmlToAttributedString.string` instead of `myLabel.attributedText = myHTMLText. htmlToAttributedString`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question got answer in comments

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension

```
extension String {
    func convertToAttributed(_ defaultFont: UIFont, textColor: UIColor ) -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = "".replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>").data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                                                    options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                                                                    documentAttributes: nil)
            else { return nil }

        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
                                            in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                            options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0))
        { (value, range, _) -> Void in
            if let oldFont = value as? UIFont {
                var newFont = defaultFont
                let isBold = oldFont.fontName.lowercased().contains("bold")
                let isItalic = oldFont.fontName.lowercased().contains("italic")
                if isBold && isItalic {
                    newFont = UIFont.bolditalicFont(ofSize: 14)
                } else if isBold {
                    newFont = UIFont.boldFont(ofSize: 14)
                } else if isItalic {
                    newFont = UIFont.italicFont(ofSize: 14)
                }
                attributedString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, range: range)
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: newFont, range: range)
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: textColor, range: range)  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
yourLabel.attributedText = string.convertToAttributed(font, textColor: textcolor)
```